# Blazor: Could not find 'downloadFileFromStream'

Tags: javascript, c#, ftp, blazor

```
 private Stream GetFileStream(Track track)
{
    Stream fileStream = _ftpService.DownloadTrack(track);

    return fileStream;
}

private async Task DownloadFileFromStream(Track track)
{
    var fileStream = GetFileStream(track);
    var fileName = track.Title;

    var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);

    await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);
}
```

Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'downloadFileFromStream' ('downloadFileFromStream' was undefined).

I cannot find any solution on the internet to this problem.

Comment: Did you added the js object as I proposed?

Comment: I am happy for you, in this case you might click on button 'issue is solved' regards. By the way I have a YouTube channel with my name on c# and blazor that you can also look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you do a 'copy paste' of code ?

It looks like your are trying to invoke a javascript method called 'downloadFileFromStream'

The message:

```
Could not find 'downloadFileFromStream'
```

indicates that this downloadFileFromStream is not defined.
to do this ensure to add a lambda object like:

```
<body>
<script>
    window.downloadFileFromStream = () => {
        // your javascript code here
    };
</script>
```

Comment: javascript code might be there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#download-from-a-stream